# Python for reading files and requests in more than 1 pod in kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, request

I am developing an application in Python that will make a query via batch of files through the request.

```
def get_func(line):
    print (line)

def main():
   file_read = open('file.txt', 'r')
   for line in file_read:
       get_func(line)
```

This application will be hosted on Kubernetes. But, if I put more than 1 pod into the application, for the same file it will run the same query more than once, repeating the lines. I wanted to run this application on more than one pod, but I wanted to have each pod run different lines in the file, without duplication of consultations.
Does anyone have a solution idea?

Comment: Use a queuing system like RabbitMQ; or have a task outside the cluster submit the jobs with something like HTTP POST requests.  (Or both.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as stated in the comments, this is not a production grade solution, just a smart way to answer your exact requirement.

You can put your app as a statefulset - each pod will get a number from 0 to your replicas number -1.

So if you'll set 3 replicas you'll have pods:

`files-reader-0`
`files-reader-1`
`files-reader-2`

Then you can pass to your pod 2 env vars:

1. The pod name using that example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/inject/dapi-envars-pod.yaml
2. The replica count which you can hardcode in your deployment files.

Then in your code read those env var, and use that formula:

`FileLines / replicaCount * podNameSuffix(which is the pod number)+1`

For example, for a file with 1000 lines and 10 pods, which lines should the 3rd pod read? easy:

`1000 / 10 * 3` to `1000 / 10 * 3-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DaemonSet for it.

DaemonSet allows you to run the same pod on each of your cluster nodes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/